# how can I install/compile PHP extension on windows

Tags: php, php-extension

I have just downloaded the php pspell extension.

But unlike the other extension it does not have .dll files to place in php ext dir. It contains lots of files.

So How can I Compile those files and create a dll file from that source?

I am running on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a WAMP stack like [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), they come with extensive extensions (pspell included) and you just need to enable it in one click.

Comment: i have configured PHP, apache manually, In this case how can I compile php extension?

Answer (score 0):

See the [instructions in the PHP wiki](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild).